# Where are QGIS desktop custom environment variables stored on disk?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux

I was tinkering with my **Environment** variables in the [System Settings of the Options panel](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#system-settings). I've done something bad and now my QGIS won't start. I'm on **Ubuntu 22.04** and have tried uninstalling with `apt-get purge --auto-remove qgis` and then reinstalling **QGIS 3.28**, but my malformed configuration seems to persist, as QGIS still fails to open. The splash screen succeeds with the "Setting up the GUI" step, but crashes at "Starting Python", which makes sense as I was messing with Python paths. Things were working before I added a custom environment variable.

Where are QGIS custom environment variables stored? I can't seem to find the relevant configuration file.

Comment: I'm on Slackware, so it might not be the same. A lot of the customized settings for programs are stored in a "." file in home. For example, "/home/jac/.qgis". Maybe start there? Another possibility is "/home/jac/.share/". That one will hold several apps' worth of settings, so you'll have to go down a directory or two.

Comment: I've looked for relevant config in /home/jac/.qgis and also /home/jac/.config but no luck. Also, I have no /home/jac/.share directory. :-(

Comment: Sorry, I meant "/home/jac/.local", not .share.

Comment: BINGO! thanks @JohnPolo that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings` -> `User profiles` -> `Open active profile folder`

or alternatively directly

`~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/`

Comment: The file relevant to my issue was `~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini`. I had to delete the extra entries in the [qgis] setting section that I had created by my tinkering.